# Will any wireless headset work with the Xbox 360?

Tags: xbox-360, audio-hardware

I want to get a wireless headset for my Xbox 360, but I would also like to be able to use it for skype and maybe even my droid.

Is this possible? if so, what am I looking for?

Answer (score 3):

You will need the [Microsoft Wireless Receiver](http://www.microsoft.com/games/en-US/Hardware/Controllers/Pages/XboxWirelessGamingReceiverforWindows.aspx/). Using this you should be able to use both the wireless headset and the wireless controler with your PC. I'm not sure if you can use it with your Droid though.

Comment: hehe for I second I thought you misinterpreted my question :-p